# How to view Standard Objects in Tabs

Tags: tab-settings

I tried creating tabs for standard objects, only the custom object is showing up in the options.Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard object has a standard tab already by default. You control the visibility at the profile level whether this tab is visible at all. Custom objects, you have control whether you create a tab for that object or not as it's "custom".

[image]

You'd have to create a Lightning/VF page tab if you'd like to do something completely custom at a standard object level through a tab.